# App runs fine in Xcode but errors when run from export

Tags: swift, postgresql, macos, code-signing

I have a Swift macOS app that has been working fine for 6 months but after the latest update the signed to run locally gives an exception in a Postgres query.

The change I made was to the UI and not anything to do with the database.

From within Xcode, it runs without error, the record is inserted correctly but once signed to run locally the SQL fails! The field it is trying to insert into is a Postgres text array.

I have cleaned the build environment even installed the source and my signing certificate on an alternative machine. The same issue works fine in XCode but running the signed code locally SQL fails.

Anyone ever come across anything like this? Its not a code bug because in that case it would not matter if it was signed or not and would have failed months ago when the save routine was written.

I dont think its a library problem as those have not been changed and I doubt they would be affected by code signing now after 6 months.

Any suggestions of what I can try gratefully received.

```
Xcode 12.5 (12E262)
macOS 11.4
PerfectPostgreSQL 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange.

I have no idea how it ever worked. Performing the well know debugging procedure of **poking and hoping** I managed to get it to fail in XCode.

I was using a method that took a string array and built a string that conformed to the TEXT[] Postgres type. This was producing a string that was not compatible how this was NOT erroring when running from Xcode still defies my reasoning!

But it is now deployed and works fine. As I was poking and hoping I am not sure what I did that resulted in the error appearing in Xcode or why it ever worked when deployed!

If you have come here because you have a similar problem I am sorry, I have nothing that will help.